# Mac OS GUI for an OCaml program

Tags: macos, user-interface, ocaml, electron

I'd like to write a GUI for an application that I wrote in OCaml I use Mac OS mainly so I'd like that it looks good at least on this platform, but even better if it can be multi-platform. I know that traditionally, people have used Lablgtk, or wrote native GUIs in a different language. I'm not familiar with most recent options though. For one thing, I may be able to compile my program to javascript. Does this give me new options? is this stable enough to be used without too much trouble? More specifically, I'm thinking about Electron.

Basically, I'd like to know what the different options are, and how they compare in term of difficulty and look.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Qt/QML via https://github.com/Kakadu/lablqml

For Electron there is https://github.com/fxfactorial/ocaml-electron

I haven't used either though so unfortunately can't comment on their look or ease of use.